# Why Parent thread does not gets executed after Child Thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, iterator, hashtable

I have written some code to traverse a Thread-safe `Hashtable` by two threads simultaneously. It's expected that only one thread could read at a time from the below code-

```
class Test7 extends Thread{
static Hashtable t=new Hashtable();
static Iterator it=t.entrySet().iterator();

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{
    t.put(1,"a");
    t.put(2,"b");
    t.put(3,"c");
    t.put(4,"d");
    t.put(5,"e");

    Test7 q=new Test7();
    q.start();

    while(it.hasNext()){
        out.println("Parent thread");
        Map.Entry m1=(Map.Entry)it.next();
        out.println(m1);
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    }
}

public void run(){
    Iterator it=t.entrySet().iterator();

    while(it.hasNext()){
        out.println("Child thread");
        Map.Entry m2=(Map.Entry)it.next();
        out.println(m2);
        try{
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e){
            out.println(1);
        }
    }
}
}
```

The output is after which the program terminates -

```
Child thread
5=e
Child thread
4=d
Child thread
3=c
Child thread
2=b
Child thread
1=a
```

Why doesn't the parent thread execute after this? Any leads would be helpful and will be appreciated.

Comment: You need to set `it` *after* you populate the `Hashtable`, otherwise you have an iterator to the end of the `Hashtable` on which `hasNext` is false.

Comment: Your iterator was created when the map had no elements, so its first `hasNext()` returned false, or it threw a `ConcurrentModificationException`. This is not a valid usage pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem with your code is that you create the iterator for the main thread before any entries are added to the `Hashtable`. For this special case the `entrySet().iterator()` method returns a `java.utils.Collections.EmptyIterator` whose `hasNext()` method always return false.

If you were to create the iterator just before the while loop the main thread would also return the entries from the `Hashtable`:

```
it=t.entrySet().iterator();
while(it.hasNext()){
    out.println("Parent thread");
    //...
}
```

**But** this only leads to interleaved output:

```
Parent thread
Child thread
5=e
5=e
Child thread
4=d
Parent thread
4=d
Child thread
3=c
```

Why? Because although the access methods of `Hashtable` (like `put`, `putAll`, `get`, `size` etc) are synchronized, the iterators you can create **are not** synchronized in general, except for the `remove` method.

Especially iterating over a `Hashtable` does not prevent other threads iterating over it as you seem to expect.